# Can't access files with a relative path when compiled into a jar

Tags: java, file-io

```
import java.io.File;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/FileT.txt").exists());
    }
}
```

Prints true when ran through the IDE

Prints false when compiled into a jar

Comment: That fact, though, is not directly related to your [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)
(which you haven't stated)

Comment: My goal was for new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/FileT.txt").exists() to be true when the program is compiled into a jar

Comment: I mean, the whole thing doesn't make much sense. For one thing, anything with `src` in it pertains to your project under development and has *no relevance at all* once your app is packaged/deployed. And that's not a goal btw, it's a *step*, and almost certainly a wrong one